# Single quotes around types in Python variable declarations

Tags: python

Python accepts this statement:

```
stop:bool = False
```

I have been told this is better:

```
stop:'bool' = False
```

Does it matter? Is there a kind of beautifier that will make my code use a single consistent style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not that the quoted style is *better*, but that it's *necessary* if you need to use a type that hasn't been defined yet.

Type hints have to be valid expressions at runtime, which means any identifier has to be defined before it can be used as a hint. If that's not possible you can supply a string that contains the name of the type.

One option for a consistent style that doesn't require *everything* to be quoted is to use `from __future__ import annotations`, which treats all type hints as strings implicitly. With that, you needn't quote *anything*.